# Custom Wordpress shortcode not displaying the form on the front end

Tags: php, wordpress, forms, plugins, shortcode

I have duplicated an existing plugin in WordPress to add an additional (identical) form for a new post type that I have created. I have renamed the shortcode in the new plugin so that it does not display the original form, yet it is not being displayed when I add the shortcode to the block editor.

I tried looking through functions.php or everywhere else to see if this shortcode is being registered anywhere else to no avail. If it's identical in code to the original plugin aside from its name, shouldn't it be displaying with its new name? Here's the code snippet of my shortcode.

```
<?php

function get_wpsisac_submission_form( $atts, $content = null ){

    $view_file  = WPSISAC_VERSION_DIR . '/templates/form.php';

    extract(
        shortcode_atts(
        array(
            "limit"             => '-1'
    ), $atts));

    ob_start();

    if (isset($_POST['submit-form'])) {

        global $wpdb;

        $artist = $_POST['artist_name'];

        $data = array(
            'post_title'=> addslashes($_POST['post_title']),
            'post_type'=>'pbrartxth',
            'post_content'=>'',
            'post_status' => 'draft',
            'post_category' => array(14),
            'meta_input' => array(
                'artist_name' => addslashes($_POST['artist_name']),
                'art_type' => $_POST['art_type'],
                'art_year' => date('Y'),
                'art_description' => addslashes($_POST['art_description']),
                'art_video_url' => $_POST['video_url'],
                'artist_age' => $_POST['artist_age'],
                'artist_address' => $_POST['artist_address_one'],
                'artist_address_two' => $_POST['artist_address_two'],
                'artist_city' => $_POST['artist_city'],
                'artist_state' => $_POST['artist_state'],
                'artist_zip' => $_POST['artist_zip'],
                'artist_email' => $_POST['artist_email'],
                'artist_phone' => $_POST['artist_phone'],
                'artist_website' => $_POST['artist_website'],
                'artist_web' => $_POST['artist_website'],
                'artist_instagram_handle' => $_POST['artist_instagram_handle'],
                // 'artist_twitter_handle' => $_POST['artist_twitter_handle'],
            )
        );

        $post_id = wp_insert_post($data);


        if (!empty($_FILES['gif_upload_field']['name'])) {
            $uploadedfile = $_FILES['gif_upload_field'];
        } else if (!empty($_FILES['jpg_upload_field']['name'])) {
            $uploadedfile = $_FILES['jpg_upload_field'];
        };

        $attachment_id = upload_user_file( $uploadedfile, $post_id );
        update_field('_thumbnail_id', $attachment_id, $post_id);


        echo "<div><p>Thank you for your submission $artist! We will review the information you have provided us.</p></div>";

        // print_r($_POST);
        // echo 'Post ID: ' . $post_id;
        // echo 'GIF File: ' . print_r($uploadedfile);
        // echo 'JPG File: ' . print_r($uploadedfile);
        // echo'</pre>';

        // exit;

    }

    include( $view_file );

    return ob_get_clean();

};

add_shortcode('th-load-form-submission','get_wpsisac_submission_form');
```

Please let me know if there is something I'm missing. This is the only instance I found that made reference to the shortcode name.

Comment: Just clarifying, you copied this into its own plugin directory and activated the plugin? And you only changed the plugin name? Are you seeing any PHP warnings or errors? I am wondering if the constant WPSISAC_VERSION_DIR is available in your plugin.

Comment: Yes, this is in its own plugin directory with a new name. The plugin is active. There aren't any errors in the console. The WPSISAC_VERSION_DIR is available in this plugin pointing to the same path as the original plugin just inside this plugin directory. That has not been changed.

Comment: Sorry I know I am asking dumb questions, but trying to narrow everything down. You are seeing no output at all and with no errors? Even when you inspect the DOM?

Comment: No worries at all. No output except the "[th-load-form-submission]" on the page. It doesn't appear to be registering the shortcode at all for some reason. But no errors appear. I'm assuming this is because it doesn't know to even look for the code and instead just sees plain text.

Comment: If it helps, I've uploaded the entire plugin directory to a Dropbox: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/9zfqrtetoou9ao7/AABJX82gdwCuizDwymcRrAg_a?dl=0

Comment: I got the form to show on my local test environment by inputting "[th-load-form-submission]" in the shortcode block. Very weird

Comment: That is very strange. I can't imagine what would be blocking it on my end. Perhaps because there are two instances of the same form? But they're in separate plugin directories. I wonder if something is being called twice globally but that doesn't make sense because the original form still functions perfectly.

Comment: I did some more digging and it does seem like more needs to be changes then just the shortcode and plugin name. The file 'wp-slick-image-slider.php' is not including any new files when you copy the plugin contents, because it checks for a defined constant which the first plugin already instantiated. Changing the name of the constants to include your duplicate files throws new errors because the duplicates are redeclaring functions, which is not allowed. It appears that the duplicated plugin was just failing silently.